# "Not to" or "To not" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> "Another compelling reason **to not** ban mobile phones is that they are
>   necessary for our daily life."

I would like to ask whether the given sentence is correct in terms of grammar, especially, the "**to not**" part seems peculiar to me; and could I use "Another reason to not ban..." instead?

Comment: The body of your question never actually uses ***not to***. If it weren't for the title of the question, I'd assume you were asking about *another reason* as opposed to *another **compelling** reason*, because that's the only difference you provide.

Comment: My carelessness Jasson! I just quoted that from an essay that I have read which listed a range of reasons not to ban mobile phones, of which my quenstion is presented. thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"reason not to ban X" and "reason to not ban X" have essentially the same meaning, although with slightly different emphasis.

In the first form, the action being considered is "banning X" and the speaker says there is reason not to take this action. In the second the "action" is "not banning X" (which is the same as "permitting X") and the speaker says that there is reason to take this action. This second form sees "not banning" as a more definite choice. But the difference is very subtle; both forms are acceptable and not uncommon, and any difference in meaning is slight.

Comment: Thanks David, your clarification is so understandable. Although I can understand the differences between the two to some extent, I definitely wouldn't able to figure out such subtle distinguish.